# Big-Oh Notation

Tags: big-o

if T(n) is O(n), then it is also correct to say T(n) is O(n2) ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes; because O(n) is a subset of O(n^2).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "subset"?

Comment: O(n) is the set of all functions whose growth is bounded asymptotically by `k.n`.  Ditto for O(n^2).  All functions in O(n) are in O(n^2) (basically by definition), therefore O(n) is a subset of O(n^2).

Comment: okay, fair enough. Just a little different terminology than I'm used to.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming

> T(n) = O(n), n > 0

Then both of the following are true

> T(n) = O(2n)
>   T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

This is because both `2n` and `n`<sup>`2`</sup> grow as quickly as or more quickly than just plain `n`. EDIT: As Philip correctly notes in the comments, even a value smaller than 1 can be the multiplier of `n`, since constant terms may be dropped (they become insignificant for large values of `n`; EDIT 2: as Oli says, all constants are insignificant per the definition of `O`). Thus the following is *also* true:

> T(n) = O(0.2n)

In fact, n<sup>2</sup> grows so quickly that you can also say

> T(n) = o(n<sup>2</sup>)

But not

> T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

because the functions given provide an asymptotic upper bound, not an asymptotically tight bound.

Comment: @tster, why not? Big-Oh is like saying `<=` ( [Cormen](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/870/if-you-could-only-have-one-programming-related-book-on-your-bookshelf-what-would/879#879), p 52); Little-Oh is analogous to `<`.

Comment: There is a difference between the terms "equals" and "is an element of" (∈). It is not valid to say T(n) = O(n) or O(<take your pick>). It is valid to say T(n) ∈ O(n) and T(n) ∈ O(n*n). This is because big O notation is in terms of sets.

Comment: @Mark, that's just another quirk of terminology (again, I cite Cormen).

Comment: +1 for thoroughness, but I would rephrase the sentence "This is because..." It is also true that T(n) is in O( 0.5 * n), so the statement that 2n grows more quickly than n is not the right thing to use in this context.

Comment: @Philip Starhill: Indeed, because the definition of O() includes an arbitrary constant scaling factor.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: Your edit is still slightly incorrect.  It's not that the constant factors "become insignificant for large values"; they're insignificant *by the definition of O()*, as it already includes an arbitrary constant scaling factor.

Comment: @Oli, I considered that to be implied, but I will edit again.

Answer (score 2):

if you mean O(2 * N)  then yes O(n) == O(2n). The time taken is a linear function of the input data in both cases

I disagree with the other answer that says O(N) = O(N*N). It is true that the O(N) function will finish in less time than O(N*N), but the completion time is not a function of n*n so it really isnt true

I suppose the answer depends on why u r asking the question

Comment: The other answer doesn't say O(N) = O(N^2), but rather has the implied meaning that any function T(N) that is O(N) is also O(N^2) (which is correct according to the formal definition of big-O)

Comment: I think you are using the definition of 'theta' in place of the definition of 'big-O'.  'big-O' only provides an upper bound on the asymptotic growth of a function.

Answer (score 0):

O also known as Big-Oh is a upper bound. We can say that there exists a C such that, for all n > N, T(n) < C g(n). Where C is a constant.

So until an unless the large co-efficient in T(n) is smaller or equal to g(n) then that statement is always valid.